# exit for loop from another python script

Tags: php, python

I'm new to python and need some help completing a project, please let me say this is not school work.
I have a for loop that controls the gpio pins on a raspberry pi the name of this file is "ledtest.py" this script is executed using the "exec" command in php, when i press a button on the page it executes the "ledtest.py" script, all that works well my led's light up and do what the program tells it to, my problem is; I will like to stop the loop sometimes if it runs too long, I would like to put a command to stop the loop on a new python file and have it executed from php when i press a second button, i have heard about the break command but don't know how to implement it any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't control one script from another script. The second script would have to do something like modify a file, and the first script would have to check that file every time it goes through its loop. Then if the file contains the stop command, it can use `break` to exit the loop.

Comment: adding your code would be a big help

Comment: save greyed out when trying to add code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while not os.path.exists("/home/pi/stop_LEDS"):
     do_blink_led()

os.remove("/home/pi/stop_LEDS")
```

then in the php just create that file ... when you want it to stop

you could make it exist with `<?php exec('touch /home/pi/stop_LEDS');?>`

try this

**index.php**

```
<?php
    if isset($_POST["stop"]){
       // create the file that will exit the ledtest loop
       exec('touch /home/pi/stop_LEDS');
       echo '<form method="POST"><input type="submit" name="start" value="start" /></form>';
    }else if isset($_POST["start"]){
       // start ledtest
       exec("ledtest.py");
       echo '<form method="POST"><input type="submit" name="stop" value="stop" /></form>';
    }else{
        echo '<form method="POST"><input type="submit" name="start" value="start" /></form>';
    }
?>
```

**ledtest.py**

```
 while not os.path.exists("/home/pi/stop_LEDS"):
     do_blink_led() # this is your method that you wrote that blinks the led

 os.remove("/home/pi/stop_LEDS")
```

Comment: interesting idea! +1 , some kind of subprocess call could also work.

Comment: except he said he was calling the script from php ... so that might be hard... I figured this would be the simplest approach

Comment: I meant from the php side, I have no idea if that is possible or not as I have no clue about php!

Comment: Im pretty sure it would be painful  :P

Comment: lol hopefully I will never have to find out

Comment: Ok now I'm really confused

Comment: this will continue blinking the LED until that file exists ....

Comment: ok tried it, didnt work but thanks anyways

Comment: it surely does ... if its not working you need to provide more details ...  this is what is know in the IT world as PEBKAC